# Alternative to "@name" for documenting the properties of `this`

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I am wondering how to document the `this.` properties a class's constructor function. For example, I've tried the `@name` tag to name my class, but it did not generate documentation for `this.foo`:

```
/**
 * @name ClassName
 * @constructor
 */
function noname (){
    /** @type {String} */
    this.foo = "bar";
}
```

I can solve it like this:

```
/**
 * @name ClassName
 * @constructor
 */
function noname (){
    /** 
    * @type {String} 
    * @name ClassName#foo
    */
    this.foo = "bar";
}
```

or in this way:

```
/**
 * @name ClassName
 * @constructor
 */
function noname (){
    /** @lends ClassName# */
    var that = this;

    /** @type {String} */
    that.foo = "bar";
}
```

However, neither is satisfactory because that would either require changing lots of existing code, or the addition of all the names of properties in jsdoc comments.

Since `@name` doesn't do the trick, is there an alternative tag that will?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `@alias` tag instead:

```
/**
 * @alias ClassName
 * @constructor
 */
function noname (){
    /** @type {String} */
    this.foo = "bar";
}
```

In general, use the `@alias` tag to rename a symbol that exists in your code; use the `@name` tag if you're documenting a symbol that does not appear in your code (for example, a method that's generated at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

@name un-binds the docblock from the following code.

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-name.html

> Warning: By using the @name tag, you are telling JSDoc to ignore the surrounding code and treat your documentation comment in isolation. In many cases, it is best to use the @alias tag instead

So any internal items would have to have proper @name too (see http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html for proper syntax).